# error: invalid combination of opcode and operands

Tags: nasm

I am new to NASM. I am getting the error:

> invalid combination of opcode and operands

on the first line below

```
mov     si,bl   ;si contains address of number string
mov     cx,7    ;once for each line
jmp     print_num ;print the number
loop    line_loop ;decrement cx, repeat if cx<>0
int     20h
```

Answer (score 1):

`si` is a 16 bit register while `bl` is a 8 bit register. You can only use **mov** instructions when the operands are both in same bits.

As a solution to your problem, use `bx` instead of `bl`

```
mov si,bx
```

It is because Intel 8086 processor uses 16 bit addressing instead of 8 bit.

By the way, you can use `esi` and `ebx` when programming 32 bit applications.